# Tried multilpe variations, but the timer won't start ticking. Where is the problem?

Tags: c#, timer

I tried to add the timer from Windows Forms, tried to use `timer1.Start()` and `Stop()`, tried to create the timer  dynamically. But nothing seems to work. When I tried working with Console, the timer ticks and everything seems fine, but as soon as I switch to Windows Application it does nothing. I guess the relation between the labels and the timer is not correct or something... Please Help!

```
    int h,m,s;
    bool isOn;

    void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RightBottomCornerLoad();
        ResetZero();

        isOn=false;
    }

    void ResetZero()
    {
        h=0;
        m=0;
        s=0;
    }

    void ButtonStartClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isOn=true;
        timer1.Enabled=true;
    }

    void ButtonStopClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isOn=false;
    }

    void ButtonResetClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isOn=false;         
        ResetZero();            
    }

    void Timer1Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(isOn)
        {
            s++;
            if(s>=60)
            {
                m++;
                s=0;

                if(m>=60)
                {
                    h++;
                    m=0;
                }
            }
        }

        ShowTime();

    }

    void ShowTime()
    {
        labelSeconds.Text=String.Format("{0:00}",s);
        labelMinutes.Text=String.Format("{0:00}",m);
        labelHours.Text=String.Format("{0:00}",h);
    }
```

Comment: Post `timer1`'s code of initialization. It's essential to check if timer settings is correct. If you drag a timer to your form from designer, right click on your code of `timer1` and click "find all reference" to see the code.

Comment: I have tried your code and it is working as aspected. So maybe there is realy a problem of the behind code of your timer. Try to create the timer new.

Comment: Have you linked the Timer's Tick event to the handler?

Comment: private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
this.timer1.Enabled = true;
this.timer1.Interval = 1000;
this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.Timer1Tick);
timer1.Enabled=true;